# Grunt Serve Dist is not minifying scripts imported through lazy loading

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, bower, grunt-build-control

I'm using Yeoman, Grunt and bower for my AngularJS application. It's working fine. I'm using bootstrap, Angular bootstrap, Angular Toaster and few other bower components. But when I do ***`grunt serve:dist`***, it is not adding all files and also not minifying the scripts which are imported in views (HTML files other   than index.html) through lazy loading.

Here is my **index.html**

```
<!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
<!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
<!-- bower:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="bower_components/angular-ui-select/dist/select.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="bower_components/angular-toastr/dist/angular-toastr.css" />
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/library.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/select2.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/select2-bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/selectize.bootstrap3.css" />
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css"> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app-style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app-theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/animate.css">
<!-- endbuild -->

</head>
<body>
</body>

<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-select/dist/select.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-toastr/dist/angular-toastr.tpls.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
    <!-- Directives -->
    <script src="scripts/directive/directives.js"></script>
    <!-- Factories -->
    <script src="scripts/factory/factories.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
```

When I do **grunt serve:dist** index.html gets updated. It removes CSS imports
inside **bower:css** and **endbower**. it removes the bootstrap CSS and only have the following.

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="bower_components/angular-ui-select/dist/select.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="bower_components/angular-toastr/dist/angular-toastr.css" />
```

I'm lading my controllers through lazy loading. My **login.html** is like following.

```
<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/controllers/auth/login.js -->
<script src="scripts/controllers/auth/login.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
<div class="box box-bordered">
<!-- Login Content -->
</div>
```

In grunt serve:dist, it minifies the HTML. but it is not updating the import file name or the file is not copying to scripts folder.

```
<script src="scripts/controllers/auth/login.js"></script> <div class="box box-bordered"> <!-- Code --></div>
```

Why it's not minifying all? or changing bower components in index? How to solve it?

Here is the **Gruntfile.js**

```
// Generated on 2015-07-06 using generator-angular 0.11.1
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

  // Load grunt tasks automatically
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  // Configurable paths for the application
  var appConfig = {
    app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
    dist: 'dist'
  };

  // Define the configuration for all the tasks
  grunt.initConfig({

    // Project settings
    yeoman: appConfig,

    // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
    watch: {
      bower: {
        files: ['bower.json'],
        tasks: ['wiredep']
      },
      js: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/**/*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:all'],
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        }
      },
      jsTest: {
        files: ['test/spec/**/*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'karma']
      },
      styles: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/**/*.css'],
        tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
      },
      gruntfile: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js']
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        },
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/**/*.html',
          '.tmp/styles/**/*.css',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
        ]
      }
    },

    // The actual grunt server settings
    connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
        hostname: 'localhost',
        livereload: 35729
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              connect.static('.tmp'),
              connect().use(
                '/bower_components',
                connect.static('./bower_components')
              ),
              connect().use(
                '/app/styles',
                connect.static('./app/styles')
              ),
              connect.static(appConfig.app)
            ];
          }
        }
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          port: 9001,
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              connect.static('.tmp'),
              connect.static('test'),
              connect().use(
                '/bower_components',
                connect.static('./bower_components')
              ),
              connect.static(appConfig.app)
            ];
          }
        }
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }
      }
    },

    // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
    jshint: {
      options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
        reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
      },
      all: {
        src: [
          'Gruntfile.js',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/**/*.js'
        ]
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc'
        },
        src: ['test/spec/**/*.js']
      }
    },

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/**/*',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git**/*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: '.tmp'
    },

    // Add vendor prefixed styles
    autoprefixer: {
      options: {
        browsers: ['last 1 version']
      },
      server: {
        options: {
          map: true,
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
          src: '**/*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/styles/'
        }]
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
          src: '**/*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/styles/'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
    wiredep: {
      app: {
        src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
        ignorePath:  /\.\.\//
      },
      test: {
        devDependencies: true,
        src: '<%= karma.unit.configFile %>',
        ignorePath:  /\.\.\//,
        fileTypes:{
          js: {
            block: /(([\s\t]*)\/{2}\s*?bower:\s*?(\S*))(\n|\r|.)*?(\/{2}\s*endbower)/gi,
              detect: {
                js: /'(.*\.js)'/gi
              },
              replace: {
                js: '\'{{filePath}}\','
              }
            }
          }
      }
    },

    // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    filerev: {
      dist: {
        src: [
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/**/*.js',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/**/*.css',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
        ]
      }
    },

    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
      html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
      options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
        flow: {
          html: {
            steps: {
              js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
              css: ['cssmin']
            },
            post: {}
          }
        }
      }
    },

    // Performs rewrites based on filerev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
      html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/**/*.html'],
      css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/**/*.css'],
      options: {
        assetsDirs: [
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles'
        ]
      }
    },

    // The following *-min tasks will produce minified files in the dist folder
    // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
    // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
    // to use the Usemin blocks.
    // cssmin: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
    //         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // uglify: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
    //         '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // concat: {
    //   dist: {}
    // },

    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    svgmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '**/*.svg',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    htmlmin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          conservativeCollapse: true,
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
          removeOptionalTags: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: ['*.html', 'views/**/*.html'],
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },

    // ng-annotate tries to make the code safe for minification automatically
    // by using the Angular long form for dependency injection.
    ngAnnotate: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
          src: '*.js',
          dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Replace Google CDN references
    cdnify: {
      dist: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
      }
    },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: [
            '*.{ico,png,txt}',
            '.htaccess',
            '*.html',
            'views/**/*.html',
            'images/**/*.{webp}',
            'styles/fonts/**/*.*'
          ]
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/images',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
          src: ['generated/*']
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'bower_components/bootstrap/dist',
          src: 'fonts/*',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      },
      styles: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        dest: '.tmp/styles/',
        src: '**/*.css'
      }
    },

    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
    concurrent: {
      server: [
        'copy:styles'
      ],
      test: [
        'copy:styles'
      ],
      dist: [
        'copy:styles',
        'imagemin',
        'svgmin'
      ]
    },

    // Test settings
    karma: {
      unit: {
        configFile: 'test/karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
      }
    }
  });


  grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'wiredep',
      'concurrent:server',
      'autoprefixer:server',
      'connect:livereload',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', 'DEPRECATED TASK. Use the "serve" task instead', function (target) {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run(['serve:' + target]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    'wiredep',
    'concurrent:test',
    'autoprefixer',
    'connect:test',
    'karma'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'wiredep',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'ngAnnotate',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'filerev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
  ]);
};
```

**UPDATE 1**

I added following in the end of Gruntfile.js

```
grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
  ]);

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-ngmin');

  ngmin: {
      controllers: {
        src: ['script/controllers/auth/login.js'],
        dest: ['script/controllers/auth/login.js']
      },
      directives: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'script',
        src: ['directive/**/*.js'],
        dest: 'script/directive'
      }
    }
```

When I do grunt serve, I get error

```
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> SyntaxError: /home/myuser/workspace/workspace1/myapp/Gruntfile.js:450
>>      dest: ['script/controllers/auth/login.js']
>>          ^
>> Unexpected token :
Warning: Task "serve" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Comment: I know this is quite old, but I am having this exact same problem. were you able to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

You have not passed optimize option in your grunt setup . this is for minification.

```
   requirejs: {
          build: {
            options: {
                 optimize: 'uglify2',
               }
          }
    }
```

If you have loaded ngmin and not using requireJS.

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-ngmin');


ngmin: {
  controllers: {
    src: ['test/src/controllers/one.js'],
    dest: 'test/generated/controllers/one.js'
  },
  directives: {
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'test/src',
    src: ['directives/**/*.js'],
    dest: 'test/generated'
  }
},
```

Comment: I'm sorry where I need to add in Gruntfile.js? Also do I need requirejs? I'm not using requirejs for lazy loading

Comment: you have no requireJS module

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not that great in this. I tried adding the code, but it gives error. please check **UPDATE 1**

Comment: please read the docs its very simple ... dest is the folder where you'll keep the minified file ,so for every thing in angular whether it is controller ,filter , factory etc. you can define it in the grunt file .. https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-ngmin

Comment: Earlier I didnt install grunt-ngmin, now I installed it. But I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83189/discussion-between-nglover-and-icode).